# Simple Selenium Test Gives XHR ERROR : 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm using selenium-rc with C# to test my asp.net mvc2 application. Currently all I am doing is opening the home page with selenium RC.

when I run my test I see the selenium remote control open in a browser and I see my application open correctly in a browser but selenium shows a 404 error and aborts the test.

In an attempt to get this working I have cut the test down to a simple console app and have changed the default selenium port here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var _selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 1234, "*chrome", "http://localhost:6666");
            _selenium.Start();
            _selenium.Open("/");

            try
            {
                _selenium.Stop();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

this fails with the error **"XHR ERROR: URL = /localhost:6666/ Response_Code = 404 Error_Message = Not Found on session 5f2e59798ae74e7cb741d50cae7e817a"**

and if you look in the running selenium console you see

```
15:53:16.238 INFO - Allocated session 5f2e59798ae74e7cb741d50cae7e817a for http://localhost:6666, launching...
15:53:16.265 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
15:53:18.325 INFO - Launching Firefox...
15:53:20.977 INFO - Got result: OK,5f2e59798ae74e7cb741d50cae7e817a on session 5f2e59798ae74e7cb741d50cae7e817a
15:53:20.980 INFO - Command request: open[/, ] on session 5f2e59798ae74e7cb741d50cae7e817a
15:53:22.654 INFO - Got result: XHR ERROR: URL = http://localhost:6666/ Response_Code = 404 Error_Message = Not Found on session 5f2e59798ae74e7cb741d50cae7e817a
```

Interesting things that I have tried are:

change the site to "google" - then my test works
change the site to "google" port 80 then it doesnt work.
moved my site from cassini to iis 7 - didnt work
made my site the default site on iis 7 eg http://localhost/ - didnt work
I've used fiddler to watch the session - all requests fired return successfully.
I've tried passing -avoidProxy and -ensureCleanSession when starting the RC server. Hasn't made any noticable difference.

If I reconfigure selenium to use the default port I get the following exception repeated over and over (once every 10 seconds / different sessionid each time). This doesn't happen once I've changed the default port but i've included it just in case.

```
16:26:38.019 WARN - POST /selenium-server/driver/?seleniumStart=true&localFrameAddress=top&seleniumWindowName=&uniqueId=sel_48694&sessionId=a87b8d6a9e444a5485a5044ef6370e2d&counterToMakeURsUniqueAndSoStopPageCachingInTheBrowser=1286810798016&sequenceNumber=4115 HTTP/1.1
java.lang.RuntimeException: sessionId a87b8d6a9e444a5485a5044ef6370e2d doesn't exist; perhaps this session was already stopped?
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.getQueueSet(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:220)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleBrowserResponse(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:131)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:245)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
```

Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: When you use it with the normal port are you getting these errors when running the tests or do they appear without any tests running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using C# and had similar problem with selenium.open method. I have refered the thread **haroonzone** posted in his answer above. and have made following changes in my code

Declare `selenium` as

```
private DefaultSelenium selenium;
```

instead of

```
private ISelenium selenium;
```

and call open method as

```
    selenium.Processor.DoCommand("open", new String[] { YOUR_URL, "true" });
```

instead of

```
    selenium.Open("YOUR_URL");
```

Additionally, you may want to call

```
selenium.SetTimeout("600000");
```

before DoCommand

Answer (score 1):

What version of Selenium Server are you using? We get this problem with Selenium Server 2.0a2. It is fixed in later versions of Selenium, so if you download the latest version of the Selenium Server and run this test against it then you wont get the XHR exception. But if you cannot update the selenium version then you can do the following. The code snippet is in Java you can have a similar in C#.

The problem is with the selenium.open method. You can find more information on the following URL.
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=408

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", port, browserString, url) {
        public void open(String url) {
            commandProcessor.doCommand("open", new String[] {url,"true"});
        }
    };
```

Comment: That doesn't compile - Are you sure that isn't java or something?

Comment: I tried creating a new class derived from DefaultSelenium but the open method isnt virtual

Comment: I have not tried adding this to our framework, because we are using selenium grid startSession method not the DefaultSelenium, another workaround is to wrap the open method with try catch block like 

try{
   selenium.open(url);
}catch (SeleniumException se){
      if (se.getMessage().contains("XHR Error"){
            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
      }
}